# Is there a CHANGEABLE ListProperty in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, addition, listproperty

Is there a CHANGEABLE `ListProperty` in JavaFX?
I need a `ListProperty` supprting `add()` and `remove()` methods, but I couldnt't find one.
`SimpleListProperty` will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

All I found is to use the initializer to set the contents, but that's not what I need.
I need to start with an empty Property end buld from there.

I cannot believe there's no such a thing; I must be blind, somehow.
Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out `ListProperty()` is an empty wrapper.
It does **not** initialize the wrapped `ObservableList<>`.
This is absolutely unclean from documentation **and** the `UnsupportedOperationException` thrown is misleading (should be a NPE).
Default constructor is useless in normal usage, use something like:

```
ListProperty<String> xxx = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
```

**NOTE:** Using a simple `ObservableList` does not work for me because I'm using `Property` methods (e.g.: `getBean()`)

Answer (score 4):

Observable list is the one you are looking for. It has add and remove methods.

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
list.add("Jaya");
list.add("Prasad");
list.add("test");
list.remove(list.indexOf("test"));
```

Comment: Close, but not exactly what I needed; see below.